# How to write annotation-based servlet mapping in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'd like to rewrite the following xml definition to annotation-based java classes:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The following does not work:

```
@Service
@RequestMapping(value = "services/*")
public class CXFStartServlet extends CXFServlet {

}
```

Result:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.destroy(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.onApplicationEvent(CXFServlet.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.onApplicationEvent(CXFServlet.java:41)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:776)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:485)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring doesn't allow defining servlets. It allows defining controllers, used by the Spring dispatcher servlet.

If you want a servlet, and no XML to map it, you simply need to use the [WebServlet annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) of the standard servlet API:

```
@WebServlet("/services")
public class CXFStartServlet extends CXFServlet {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add the import for CXF in your spring configuration file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schema/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
  ...
</beans>
```

You can take a look at [embedding-cxf-inside-spring](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html) and [JAX-RS_Spring_CXF](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/blog/blog.php?/archives/7-Simple-JAX-RS-Web-Service-in-Java-with-Spring-and-CXF.html) for the specification and an example.

Comment: The imports are not required anymore nowadays.